# Why is JSON adding +'s into my string?

Tags: jquery, python, json

I'm sending a message to the server via jQuery and when it gets to the Python part, +'s get added into my string :(

jQuery

```
// RESPONSE BUTTON:
$('.friend_response').unbind('click').bind('click', function () {

    var choice = $(this).siblings('p').text().toLowerCase(),
    theBtn     = $(this),
    id         = $('.friend_id_details').data('friend-id'),
    message    = "I would like to add you to my friend network.";

    if (choice === 'accept') {
        $(theBtn).removeClass('big_accept');
        $(theBtn).addClass('big_accept_clicked');
        $('.big_deny').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $('.big_deny').css('cursor','auto');
        $('.button_accept p').text('Accepting...');
        sendFriendResponse(message_id, message, id, '/accept');

    } else if (choice === 'deny') {
        $(theBtn).removeClass('big_deny');
        $(theBtn).addClass('big_deny_clicked');
        $('.big_accept').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $('.big_accept').css('cursor','auto');
        $('.button_deny p').text('Denying...');
        sendFriendResponse(message_id, ' ',     id, '/deny');
    }
});
```

^ Above clearly my message is just `"I would like to add you to my friend network."`

My postToServerWithAjax looks like:

```
$.ajax({
        type: postMethod,
        url: url,
        cache: false,
        // data: JSON.stringify(params),
        data: params,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        statusCode: {
            200: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                //console.log('200');
                callback(data);
            },
            201: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                //console.log('201');
                callback(data);
            },
            400: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                //console.log('400');
                callback(data);
            }
        }
    });
```

The params object:

```
Object {message: "I would like to add you to my friend network.", id: 6}
```

Finally in Python:

```
@view_config(route_name="accept:request", request_method='POST')
def accept_request(self):
    success_msg = ["You accepted the request"]
    error_msgs = ["Bacon is missing, we're looking into the issue"]

    try:
        json = self.body
        id = int(json['id'])
        message = str(json['message'])

        print id
        print message

        self.ctx.messaging.accept(id, message)
        value = {'result': 'success', 'message': random.choice(success_msg)}

    except Exception, err:
        value = {'result': 'error', 'message': random.choice(error_msgs)}
        print err

    return self.emit_json(value)
```

And the print statements :(

```
6
I+would+like+to+add+you+to+my+friend+network.
```

I tried just `json['message']` too, but same results

Comment: That's what happens to spaces when they are encoded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not sending JSON; you are sending a regular `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request instead. A X-WWW-Form-URLEncoded POST body uses [URL percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding); spaces are encoded as `+` characters in that encoding.

jQuery does this because `data` is not already a string. You must encode the data to a JSON yourself:

```
$.ajax({
        type: postMethod,
        url: url,
        cache: false,
        data: JSON.stringify({'params': params}),
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        statusCode: {
            200: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                //console.log('200');
                callback(data);
            },
            201: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                //console.log('201');
                callback(data);
            },
            400: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                //console.log('400');
                callback(data);
            }
        }
    });
```

Setting the correct content type for the data you send is always a good idea.

Setting the `dataType` argument only matters for the *response*, telling `jQuery` to decode the data *received* as JSON. It has no bearing on how `data` is sent to the server.

It looks as if you are using Pyramid for the Python side; you want to use [`Request.json_body`](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/webob.html#request-json-body) to access the JSON-encoded data as a Python object.

Comment: Ah thanks! Just found out that I could do this in Python too `id, message = int(self.param("id")), self.param("message")`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is going on, but having the same problem again...

**First try in Python**

```
for char in title:
    if char in "+":
        cleaned_title = title.replace(char, ' ')
```

**2nd attempt, better in jQuery & Python**

```
titleVar = $('#the-title').val();

if (titleVar.indexOf(' ')) {
    var titleCleaned = titleVar.split(' ').join('%20');
}
```

Then in Python:

```
import urllib2
if 'params' in self.body:
    params = self.body['params']
    pars = urllib2.unquote(params)
    cleaned = json.loads(pars)
```

^ Much better then doing a for loop... or trying to fix this crap below:

Just cannot figure out what is the exact perfect setup for a jQuery Ajax call:

```
var invokeServerWithJSON = function(url, params, callback, postMethod) {

    WHOAT.analytics.trackPageView(url);
    $.ajax({
        type: postMethod,
        url: url,
        cache: false,
        data: {'params': JSON.stringify(params)},
        // contentType: "application/json",
        // success: callback,
        // dataType: 'JSON',
        statusCode: {
            200: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                callback(data);
            },
            201: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                callback(data);
            },
            400: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                callback(data);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `data: {'params': **somestring**}` *sends a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded ` POST body* again, because it is not a string.

Comment: Use `data: JSON.stringify({'params': params})` instead. Then you are JSON-converting *the whole object*. Set the content type header correctly, and the server side will see JSON being posted.

Comment: The `dataType` option tells jQuery how to handle *what the server sends*.

Comment: Thanks, can you update your original answer with that exact string? `data: JSON.stringify({'params': params})`